# How do cut-through switch behavior when messages are long and short

Tags: networking, switch-statement, collision

Say i have a 2x2 cut-through switch. It's processing long message. 
What if the messages are now all short message. What will happen?
I would assume the collision rate will be lower since message is short now. Is that correct?

And what if the message length varies a lot. Sometimes long and sometimes short. I would assume short message are more likely to be dropped. Is this correct?

Comment: Switches don't have collisions; that's the point of a switch.

Comment: a 2x2 switch.  Saying input A, B,   output C,D.  A has a message, header points to C,  and B receive a message which points to C as well at the same time.  This is called output collision right? Since it's cut-through switch.

Comment: No. Collisions happen on half-duplex links. Each switch port defines a different collision domain. When set to full duplex, there will not be any collisions on the link. Collisions don't happen inside switches. Hubs (layer-1 devices) have collisions since they are half duplex by nature, but switches are layer-2 devices, and one of the primary advantages of switches is to break up collision domains.